# addFrameScript does not work correctly with Air 2.6

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5

I have coded two programs using flash cs5.5. Both of them use **addFrameScript** to organize the code on each frame.

The first one I exported on Air For Android and had no problem with it.

The second one I exported on Air 2.6 and a problem occurred.

If I go from frame to frame in order (using gotoAndStop()) then frame script loads perfectly.

But when I use the same method (**gotoAndStop()**) to go back to a previous frame, all of the stage instances on my lower layers are not loaded properly so I get **ERROR 1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference**

Funny thing, when I move them up to the first two layers, things start working again.

But I still want to keep them in their own layers. Some help please?

Thanks in advance

EDIT 1:

I just found out that if move them up to a new layer then the older elements in that layer will not be loaded properly. It's like only the first few children of the display list are loaded.

**EDIT 2:**

**If I change it to Air For Android, the problem disappears !! my mind is blowing right now**

Comment: if it works forward but not backward it sounds like the are dependency problems.  Have you looked to see if like frame 2 adds something that frame 3 needs?  or frame 4 removes it so going backward it isn't there any longer?

Comment: I will see to it. But then it works if I move the element up the display list?

Comment: yeah.. if something like in frame 4 it says removeChild(stuff) and stuff contains 3 clips you are trying to access.. then moving them out of stuff and up in the display list would "fix" the error that they no longer exist in frame 3 when you go backward.  Just a thought...

Comment: when you said "when I move them up to the first two layers" do you mean in display children... or do you mean literally in the layers on the timeline? also paste your addFrameScript code samples in here so we can see that

Comment: literally the layers on the timeline. So what I observe is that elements on higher layer are loaded correctly while those on lower layers are not

Comment: since you are using frame scripts... it may be a top down v/s bottom up load order issue... since you said moving them up affects the results